# Multi-user Dropbox sync via API in Web app

Tags: synchronization, dropbox, cloud-hosting, dropbox-api

I have a Web app where I want to provide users with the ability to authorize their Dropbox accounts for file sharing & sync.

Basically, if there are 3 users: User A, User B and User C, then they should be able to hookup their Dropbox accounts (simple enough to do using OAuth) to my app, after which there will be a new shared folder (say MyApp) created under their Dropbox folder. My Web app should be able to list all files (under the shared MyApp folder) shared between the 3 users. If any of the 3 users adds, edits or deletes a file in the shared MyApp folder, then the change should reflect in my Web app for all 3 users.

Just trying to figure out the best possible and simple way to do this in my app.

Answer (score 3):

The Dropbox API isn't built to automatically enable cross-account syncing like this, but rather to enable users to access their own accounts/files. However, there is a useful call "/copy_ref" that you can use to copy files between accounts easily:

[/copy_ref documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#copy_ref)

Beyond that, you'll need to handle the rest of the logic yourself.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Looks like I'll have to call /delta periodically and then use /copy_ref (as you've suggested) to mirror the files between user accounts, but I'm not sure about a few things: 1) scalability of periodic /delta calls for multiple users (it will bog down for say 1000 users) and 2) handling file overwrites (User A uploads a file, then User B uploads a file with the same name, User C overwrite a file with the same name) etc.